# Find all files a user can read from

Tags: find

At first, I wanted to simply use:

```
find /etc -type f -perm -004
```

And it did work. But then there were two files from which a current user could not read, but a group this user was in could access it anyway. So it didn't work properly.

I think this problem is solvable by writing a small script and iterating over each group. But is there a simpler way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
find /etc -type f -readable
```

From `man find`:

> **-readable**
>   Matches files which are readable.  This takes into account access control lists and other permissions artifacts which the
>   **-perm** test ignores.  This test makes  use  of              the  **access**(2) system call, and so can be fooled by NFS servers which do
>   UID mapping (or root-squashing), since many systems implement
>   **access**(2) in the client's kernel              and so cannot make use
>   of the UID mapping information held on the server.

**Limitation**:  This won't find readable files if they are under a directory that is not readable.  (Hat tip [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima).)